# How to configure the npm install comnand to "npm install --legacy-peer-deps" in Microsoft AppCenter while building a react native app

Tags: react-native, azure-pipelines, build.gradle, npm-install, visual-studio-app-center

[File Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdwnH.png)

I am trying to build my react native app from App Center. I have dependency conflicts, while running in VSCode I use the command "npm install --legacy-peer-deps" but in App center, how do I configure the same command not just npm install so that node_modules are generated and build does not fail? Thanks in advance!

I found this article but it did not make complete sense to me.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/custom/scripts/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add an `.npmrc` file to the root of your project, and include this line:

`legacy-peer-deps=true`

This gives context to the build process about your preferences for npm.

Comment: This might be it. I have somehow built the app by reverting the lock version of package_lock.json to v1. 
I have added the file and edit this comment when I build the app next time.

Comment: thanks man, I have been really confused for the past 6 hours. The project was okay but then on latest change it decided to break when building

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have been encountered with the dependency conflicts issue.

This is a dependency issue, you can ignore it and install npm packages by adding command --force or --legacy-peer-deps

`npm install react-rating-tooltip --force`