# how to solve npm error in next js project

Tags: reactjs, azure, npm, github-actions

I am a next js/react js project. In my local it works perfectly and any updates on the page are also updated on the site. I have deployed this project with azure and my repo is in Github Action. I have also Github Action setup. I have made a new branch and made some changes there, finally I merged this branch to main branch but my changes are not going live. In Github Action, under Build and Deploy it shows following error

```
App Directory Location: '/' was found.
Looking for event info
Starting to build app with Oryx
Azure Static Web Apps utilizes Oryx to build both static applications and Azure Functions. You can find more details on Oryx here: https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx
---Oryx build logs---


Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues

Oryx Version: 0.2.20221103.1, Commit: a2c65dde152b749fea395f4d1242ea9350942258, ReleaseTagName: 20221103.1

Build Operation ID: |c+FkE1pA5Rs=.7d546986_
Repository Commit : 065130ddcad0d0d8b0c5b136069ae0f375d3d64e

Detecting platforms...
Detected following platforms:
  nodejs: 16.18.0
Version '16.18.0' of platform 'nodejs' is not installed. Generating script to install it...
Detected the following frameworks: Next.js


Source directory     : /github/workspace
Destination directory: /bin/staticsites/ss-oryx/app


Downloading and extracting 'nodejs' version '16.18.0' to '/opt/nodejs/16.18.0'...
Detected image debian flavor: bullseye.
Downloaded in 1 sec(s).
Verifying checksum...
Extracting contents...
performing sha512 checksum for: nodejs...
Done in 2 sec(s).

Removing existing manifest file
Creating directory for command manifest file if it does not exist
Creating a manifest file...
Node Build Command Manifest file created.

Using Node version:
v16.18.0

Using Npm version:
8.19.2

Running 'npm install --unsafe-perm'...


added 119 packages, and audited 120 packages in 4s

26 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Running 'npm run build'...


> nextjs-static-website@0.1.0 build
> next build && next export

info  - Loaded env from /github/workspace/.env.local
Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
https://nextjs.org/telemetry

info  - using build directory: /github/workspace/.next
Error: Could not find a production build in the '/github/workspace/.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the static export. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-export-no-build-id
    at /github/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:62:19
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/github/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)


---End of Oryx build logs---
Oryx has failed to build the solution.

For further information, please visit the Azure Static Web Apps documentation at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/
If you believe this behavior is unexpected, please raise a GitHub issue at https://github.com/azure/static-web-apps/issues/
Exiting
0s
```

Please let me know how can i solve this issue. I have also ran npm run build and npm start before making commit.
Thanks

i am expecting help

Answer (score 1):

1- Specify node version and npm version (that you r using locally) in package.json

e-g:

"engines": {
"node": "14.17.4",
"npm": "6.14.13"
}

2-Create .npmrc file on the root directory with following text:

engine-strict=true